# Underscore template can't access model data

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to render a collection of views from a template, but I can't access my model data in the view template.  If I place a `<% debugger %>` call in the template, I can see the patient variable in local scope as an object, and can also access properties of the model from the console, eg. `patients.first_name`.  But I've tried every permutation I can think of in the template to access model values and can't seem to get the data (ie. `<%= patient.first_name %>`, `<%= patient['first_name'] %>` result in "`Can't find variable: patient`").

Notably, the click handler in the `PatientView` outputs the correct 'id' property for the individual view, so the model data is clearly getting passed into the view.

```
        (function () {
        Patient = Backbone.Model.extend({});
        PatientCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Patient
        });

        PatientListView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: "div",

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, "renderPatient");
            },

            renderPatient: function (model) {
                console.log(model); //<--object with 'attributes' property containing patient model
                var patientView = new PatientView({model: model});
                patientView.render();
                $(this.el).append(patientView.el);
            },

            render: function () {
                this.collection.each(this.renderPatient);
            }
        });

        PatientView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: "div",
            events: {
                "click button": "clicked"
            },

            clicked: function (e) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                var id = this.model.get("id");
                console.log(id);
            },

            render: function () {
                console.log(this.model.toJSON()); //<--object with all model properties
                var template = _.template($("#patients-item-view").text());
                template({patient: this.model.toJSON()});
                $(this.el).append(template);
            }
        });

        var items = new PatientCollection(patientData.data);

        var view = new PatientListView({collection: items});

        view.render();

        $("#patient-data").html(view.el);
    })();
```

Template is large, but abbreviated for now and has only one reference to model data:

```
<script type="text/template" id="patients-item-view">
    <div class="container-fluid patient-data-bar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <%= patient.first_name %>
            </div>
</script>
```

When run, patient is showing as undefined/can't find in console.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_.template` returns a function that you then use to transform data into an interpolated string. In your `render` method you feed that function to `jQuery.append` but it does not have access to the data at that point.

Try

```
render: function () {
    var template = _.template($("#patients-item-view").text());
    var html = template({patient: this.model.toJSON()});
    this.$el.append(html); // views have a cached version of the element 
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for the help...I did discover this (or similar) solution after much effort.  I went with:

Comment: var template = _.template($("#patients-item-view").text());
                    var vars = { patient: this.model.toJSON() };
                    var html = template(vars);
                    this.$el.append(html);

Answer (score 0):

```
                var template = _.template($("#patients-item-view").text());
                var vars = { patient: this.model.toJSON() };
                var html = template(vars);
                this.$el.append(html);
```

also worked for reason posted below.